# Writing a hexadecimal number to a file

Tags: c++

How can I write the string representation of a hexadecimal number into a file? For example, if I have a hexadecimal value `0x001A` (which is `26` in decimal) I want it written to a file as a hexadecimal string `0x001A` and not as a decimal string `26` or a stream of the raw bytes.

Comment: how are you looking at the file?  it 'stores it' as the hex value, i'm pretty sure, but just chooses to display it back to you as the decimal. Have you tried to read it back with another c++ routine, then do a logical comparison?

Answer (score 4):

You can force hexadecimal writing of numbers using the `std::hex` modifier:

```
std::cout << std::hex << 10 << std::endl;
```

This outputs "a". You can add the "0x" to have the representation complete. You can also turn them into uppercase by adding the `std::uppercase` after the `std::hex` to output the hexadecimal number in uppercase letters, also `std::setfill('0')` to fill the left sizes with '0', and `std::setw(X)` to set the desired width.

So, for example, 3 hex digits, uppercase letters and a '0' fill:

```
std::cout << "0x" << std:hex << std::uppercase << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << 10 << std::endl;
```

will print exactly `"0x00A"`.

Comment: Note that you need to turn "hex mode" off as the state is does not clear after single output; use `std::dec` to switch back to decimal notation.  However, `std::setfill` and `std::width` clear themselves after a single output, so you need to use those before each outputting each number.

Comment: It's often useful to make a temporary `std::stringstream`, set the flags on it and then send the stream's `.str()` to the `std::cout`, so that `cout`'s state is not modified.